# Pad byte[] to 16-byte multiple for AES Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays, aes

I currently have a function [C#] which takes a byte[] and an alignment to set it to, but during encryption, an error is thrown every once in awhile.

```
    private byte[] AlignByteArray(byte[] content, int alignto)
    {
        long thelength = content.Length - 1;
        long remainder = 1;

        while (remainder != 0)
        {
            thelength += 1;
            remainder = thelength % alignto;
        }
        Array.Resize(ref content, (int)thelength);
        return content;
    }
```

Does anyone see any issues with the function? I'm getting errors that the content size is not valid during AES encryption, suggesting that it is not padding right.

Comment: I don't think you want "align".  What you're talking about is padding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
private static void PadToMultipleOf(ref byte[] src, int pad)
{
    int len = (src.Length + pad - 1) / pad * pad;
    Array.Resize(ref src, len);
}
```

Comment: I think you would want to return src or pass src by ref.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's 0x16 and not 16? (I thought it was 16 so I'm assuming that).

Edit: Any decent compiler should turn `(x / 16)` into `(x >> 4)`.

```
int length = 16 * ((content.Length + 15) / 16);
Array.Resize(ref content, length);
```

Edit 2: For general purpose:

```
int length = alignment * ((content.Length + alignment - 1) / alignment);
Array.Resize(ref content, length);
```